# Dynamic where clause in ORACLE

Tags: oracle, plsql, where-clause

The requirement is to fetch results from STUDENTS table.
**If zero is passed in as student id,no more filtering on the studentid is required.**

```
PROCEDURE getResults (      
    inStudentId      IN  NUMBER,
    inSectionId      IN  NUMBER,
    inRowLimit       IN  NUMBER,
    outResultsData   OUT gphResultsData
  ) AS
    stStudentId  VARCHAR2(50) := '';
  BEGIN
    outResultsData := gphResultsData();
    IF inStudentId = '0' THEN
      stStudentId := '%';
    ELSE
      stStudentId := TO_CHAR(inStudentId);
    END IF;

    FOR rResults IN (
      SELECT
        RESULTS.STUDENT_ID,
        RESULTS.STUDENT_NAME
      FROM
        RESULTS
      WHERE
        RESULTS.STUDENT_ID LIKE stStudentId  AND -- not a good idea
        RESULTS.SECTION_ID  =   inSectionId  AND
        ROWNUM <= inRowLimit
    ) LOOP
      outResultsData.extend;
      outResultsData(outResultsData.last).studentId   :=  rResults.STUDENT_ID;
      outResultsData(outResultsData.last).studentName :=  rResults.STUDENT_NAME;
    END LOOP;

  EXCEPTION
    WHEN others THEN
      ...
```

I have come up with the above solution - which is definitely not ideal as

*inStudentId is converted to STRING using TO_CHAR and then subjected to LIKE*.

I guess the better way would be to **dynamically generate and execute the where clause.** That is -

**if inStudentId = 0 ,**

```
SELECT
    RESULTS.STUDENT_ID,
    RESULTS.STUDENT_NAME
FROM
    RESULTS
WHERE
    RESULTS.SECTION_ID  =   inSectionId  AND
    ROWNUM <= inRowLimit
```

**if inStudentId is not zero,**

```
SELECT
    RESULTS.STUDENT_ID,
    RESULTS.STUDENT_NAME
  FROM
    RESULTS
  WHERE
    RESULTS.STUDENT_ID  = inStudentId  AND
    RESULTS.SECTION_ID  = inSectionId  AND
    ROWNUM <= inRowLimit
```

Any pointer on how to best solve this problem will be a great help.

Comment: If you wanted, you could put the condition right into the `WHERE` clause: `RESULTS.SECTION_ID  = DECODE(inSectionId, 0, RESULTS.SECTION_ID, inSectionId)`

Comment: It is best to avoid DECODE when writing out the full logical condition doesn't become too complicated; then the code "speaks for itself," it is easier to maintain and modify, etc. Like in CarloCe's solution.

Comment: @OriginalPoster:  Do you need to do this in PL/SQL? This seems like a job for plain SQL. Or is there additional processing and you just showed us the part where you had trouble?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have the types:

```
CREATE TYPE gphResult IS OBJECT(
  student_id INT,
  student_name VARCHAR2(50)
);
/

CREATE TYPE gphResultsData IS TABLE OF gphResult;
/
```

Then you can avoid the loop using `BULK COLLECT INTO` like this:

```
PROCEDURE getResults (      
    inStudentId      IN  NUMBER,
    inSectionId      IN  NUMBER,
    inRowLimit       IN  NUMBER,
    outResultsData   OUT gphResultsData
  ) AS
    stStudentId  VARCHAR2(50) := '';
  BEGIN
    SELECT gphResult( STUDENT_ID, STUDENT_NAME )
    BULK COLLECT INTO outResultsData
    FROM   RESULTS
    WHERE  ( inStudentId = 0 OR student_id = inStudentId )
    AND    SECTION_ID =  inSectionId
    AND    ROWNUM     <= inRowLimit;
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN others THEN
      ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to do it is the following:

```
PROCEDURE getResults (      
    inStudentId      IN  NUMBER,
    inSectionId      IN  NUMBER,
    inRowLimit       IN  NUMBER,
    outResultsData   OUT gphResultsData
  ) AS
  BEGIN
    outResultsData := gphResultsData();
    FOR rResults IN (
      SELECT
        RESULTS.STUDENT_ID,
        RESULTS.STUDENT_NAME
      FROM
        RESULTS
      WHERE
        (RESULTS.STUDENT_ID  = inStudentId OR inStudentId = 0)  AND 
        RESULTS.SECTION_ID  =   inSectionId  AND
        ROWNUM <= inRowLimit
    ) LOOP
      outResultsData.extend;
      outResultsData(outResultsData.last).studentId   :=  rResults.STUDENT_ID;
      outResultsData(outResultsData.last).studentName :=  rResults.STUDENT_NAME;
    END LOOP;

  EXCEPTION
    WHEN others THEN
      ...
```

Comment: Or, even simpler, `WHERE inStudentId IN (0, RESULTS.STUDENT_ID) AND` (etc.)